# Execute shell script on server using Ansible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible

I have to run shell script on multiple server using Ansible. I am using following code.

```
-name: start script
 hosts: list_of_host
 become: yes
 gather_facts: no
 role:
   - startscript
```

in startscript i have below code...

```
-name: start script
 shell: /bin/bash /home/ansible/test_script.sh
 chnaged_when: false
```

Test_script is forever running process on sever. so when i am executing this command it's not coming out from that server. I need that it should start script on server and come out and go to another server to start script.

Answer (score 1):

If `/home/ansible/test_script.sh` is "forever running", you should convert that to a service and start it via systemctl.

Obviously ansible would wait for the `shell:` command to complete..

`shell` should not be used for "forever running" scripts.

You can also start the `/home/ansible/test_script.sh` by starting a `screen` and executing the script within it, so it continues to run after ansible exits,

or you can try and push that script to background execution by adding `&` at the end of your `shell:` command, as well as prefixing the command with `nohup` so it is not terminated when ansible's ssh connection disconnects

Comment: *by adding & at the end of your shell: command* ... as well as prefixing it with `nohup` so it is not terminated when ansible's ssh connection disconnects